# How to store data in a class from config file and read them at runtime overall the project?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an `asp.Net MVC` web application, and I have several `XML` configuration files, each for a specific client, under a folder in the project. What I need to do is at runtime, I need to read from a specific xml file, based on the URL, and save the file values into a class, and then read these properties in all the classes. In other words, if I have these two xml files: **firstCompany.xml** and **secondCompany.xml**, and the url is www.firstcompany.com, then I need to read from **firstCmompany.xml**, and then store all the values in a class that can be used in all the classes in the app.

Comment: There are many and many ways to share data among multiple classes. What have you tried so far? How many components needs access to configuration? Only the controllers or it can be _any_ object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is to create a `static` class, and add the needed info as properties inside. And on startup, you can fill these properties and call them whenever you want and wherever you need of course without initializing the class. For example:

```
public static class My_Page_Base
{
    private static RequestContext _RequestContext;
    public static RequestContext RequestContext
    {
        get { return _RequestContext; }
        set { _RequestContext = value; }
    }

    private static string _connectionString;
    public static string connectionString
    {
        get { return _connectionString; }
        set { _connectionString = value; }
    }
}
```

And when you need to set or get these properties, you just have to call them as follows:

```
// set the connection string property
My_Page_Base.connectionString = "you set here the connection string";
// get the connection string property
string conStr = My_Page_Base.connectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could populate a class object with the data and then place that data object in a session.

Then you can access that object anywhere within the controller or view. Only while that session is alive tho.

Comment: You will need to consider the amount and type of data. If its sensitive, there is always the option of encrypting the data in the session data claas.